# Zooming and Moving of Swf Loader Content

Tags: apache-flex

I want to zooming/scaling swf content of particular values like x,y,width,height.That selected coordinates/selected are will be visible to the container.

I am using SwfLoader to load swf content and i want zoom.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think it is not possible to zoom perticular area of swfloader, you can use scaleX, scaleY property to zoom your swfloader by certain percent, but if you want to zoom a perticular area then you have to scale whole swf and arrange swf's horizontal and vertical scroll position so that selected area would be come in the center of the screen. it looks like zooming the selected area but it actually zoom whole swf....